# powerMockito mock File objects

Tags: java, mockito

I have problem mock whenNew(File.class) using PowerMockito. Here is my method I want to test:

```
public void foo() {
    File tmpFile = new File("Folder");
    if (!tmpFile.exists()) {
        if (!configFolder.mkdir()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't create folder");
        }
    }
    File oneFileInFolder = new File(tmpFile, "fileOne.txt");
    if (oneFileInFolder.exists()){
        //do something
    } 
}
```

Here is test code I wrote:

```
static File mockFile;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //....some code 
    mockFolder = mock(File.class);
    when(mockFolder.getPath()).thenReturn("Folder");
    when(mockFolder.exists()).thenReturn(true);
    whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn(mockFolder);
    //...some code
}
```

But when I debug my testcase, I still see a real folder created in my pwd. I don't want folders created when I run my testcases. Any idea?

Comment: Throw a `verify(mockFolder).mkdir()` and see what happens -- maybe your mock is not used? Or maybe you set Mockito to call through to real methods? YOu never stubbed `mkdir()` in this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you haven't specified this in your question, the following may be missing:

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassYoureCreatingTheFileInstanceIn.class)
```

According to the [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects):

> Note that you must prepare the class creating the new instance of MyClass for test, not the MyClass itself. E.g. if the class doing new MyClass() is called X then you'd have to do @PrepareForTest(X.class) in order for whenNew to work.

In other words, `X` is the class that contains `foo()` in your example.